# I try to set some values to an array of integers but the values won't stick

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my code:

```
int[][] coordX = new int[10000][10000];
int[][] coordY = new int[10000][10000];
int cX = 0;
int cY = 0;

Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int width = (int) (screenSize.getWidth());
int height = (int) (screenSize.getHeight());
BufferedImage dirt = null;
{
    try {
        dirt = ImageIO.read(new File("res/dirt.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    for (int y = 0; y <= height; y = y + 50) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= width; x = x + 50) {
            g.drawImage(dirt, x, y, 50, 50, Color.BLACK, this);
            coordX[cX][cY] = cX;
                coordY[cX][cY] = cY; 
            cX = cX + 1;
            System.out.println("X=" + coordX[cX][cY]);
        }
        cY = cY + 1;
        cX = 0;
        System.out.println("Y=" + coordY[cX][cY]);
    }
}
```

The console outputs all the "X=" values as zero, and same for the "Y=", however, when I print the "cX" and "cY" values on their own, they are counting as intended. The problem only seems to arise when I try to store the "cX" and "cY" values in an array.

Comment: You are printing the values after incrementing cX and Cy, therefore they have not been assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing cX *prior* to printing

```
   cX = cX + 1;
   System.out.println("X=" + coordX[cX][cY]);
```

i.e. you're not printing the element you've just populated. You'll always get the default (uninitialised) int element value (0).

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing `cX` and `cY` before printing. Try this:

```
coordX[cX][cY] = cX;
coordY[cX][cY] = cY; 
System.out.println("X=" + coordX[cX][cY]);
System.out.println("Y=" + coordY[cX][cY]);
cX = cX + 1;
```

Comment: Wow, I feel so dumb. Thank you :)